# External IP not working on Kubernetes in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kubernetes, coreos

I'm following this guide [CoreOS + Kubernetes - Step By Step](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html) in a VirtualBox VM's. Everything working until i need expose services as extenal_ips to my host. When a create my [guestbook-service.json](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/examples/guestbook-go/guestbook-service.json) a external ip should be created, like the image bellow.

```
NAME        CLUSTER_IP       EXTERNAL_IP    PORT(S)      SELECTOR
guestbook   10.0.207.218     146.148.81.8   3000/TCP     app=guestbook
```

But instead i'm having the following

```
NAME        CLUSTER_IP       EXTERNAL_IP    PORT(S)      SELECTOR
guestbook   10.0.207.218                    3000/TCP     app=guestbook
```

My VM's have a Bridge Network and a NAT Network configured, and CoreOS with static IP's.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "external IP" feature needs cloud provider's support. In your case you might want to explore the nodePort option.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#type-nodeport